# android speech recognition emotion detector

Tags: android, speech-recognition

i would like to create an emotion speech recognition application in android which will detect the emotion of the users through getting the sound of their voice. is it possible to make this kind of app in android?if yes, can you give me links that will help me to make this possible. thanks!

Comment: Google has a speech recognition system. I don't know if Google has emotions though.

Comment: @JeremyD, I meant Google Search by the way =)

Comment: sounds like homework to me...

Comment: yes i did. actually right now i tried using the recognizerintent which now getting the speech of the user but im now stacked and i don't know what method i should used next and how am i going to implement the feature extraction. do you think it's possible?

Comment: Hard homework then..:) On what are you stuck exactly? What results do you have? Any example? Data?

Comment: @JeremyD haha yes Google supports speech recognition and i've already implemented it but my problem now is i don't know wat are the things i need to do after implementing the Google speech recognition. i mean like with the feature extraction and other algorithms possible to use,classifications. do u know any links which will help me?

Comment: If you just Google for your requirement, it will give you many open source API's implemented in Java(and some specifically for Android). For your specific requirement(emotion recognition) you might have to explore some of these API's and work on them. Your idea sounds innovative. Emotions in a voice can be categorized using pitch of sound, intervals between pauses and the words being used.

Comment: As suggested in some answers, there are many academic papers exploring this. I thought this might be helpful too, it is more of a business-centric article summarizing some current thinking about emotion detection in voice applications - http://www.callcentrehelper.com/does-emotion-detection-really-work-9047.htm

Comment: this is indeed an interesting topic.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7673736/emotion-detection-in-speech

Answer (score 4):

In any software application, you need three things:

Inputs --> Processing --> Outputs

So you will have to split this project into these three categories:

1. INPUTS: Recording voice data
2. PROCESSING: Run an algorithm on the recorded voice file for emotion detection
3. OUTPUTS: Write an emotion to the screen

To achieve number one is quite simple: http://www.benmccann.com/blog/android-audio-recording-tutorial/

The second part is more difficult, you will have to do some research and read some papers: http://www.google.co.za/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CGoQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcs229.stanford.edu%2Fproj2011%2FVeitZilberMordkovich-DetectingEmotionInHumanSpeech.pdf&ei=uvgPUMXRIcW3hQfA64DgAw&usg=AFQjCNEwLeC9R8jL-HOoBS6QWu-6dbRabQ

http://www.google.co.za/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CGwQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcs229.stanford.edu%2Fproj2007%2FShahHewlett%2520-%2520Emotion%2520Detection%2520from%2520Speech.pdf&ei=uvgPUMXRIcW3hQfA64DgAw&usg=AFQjCNFGwlKlcNyjG4uK4Hbmyy6emuYpIA

The third part is the easiest - and will be left to you as an exercise.

Comment: thank you for this links i'll try the first one with the recording voice data. actually im now using the recognizerintent for the speech recognition but i'll try this link you've suggested. thanks again

Comment: and oh yes i have also gone reading and researching more on about emotions and emotion detection in speech recognition. and i am now trying to implement them through creating them in code

Answer (score 3):

you could also do a very simple emotion detection on the *words* returned by Google's speech recognition engine. this does not capture the emphasis with which  words are spoken but is currently probably the much more realistic approach.